# Excel - How to allow for Text to Columns in a protected sheet?

Tags: excel

I could not find an answer to this, neither on Stack or on the wild web. I have a sheet where I need users to be able to use Text to Columns, however, I also need to protect the sheet. Everything works fine if Excel automatically does this (from Text to Column "short-term memory"), but I cannot access the option when protection is enabled.

It is not that any text is spilling onto locked cells, it's just that the option is greyed out after protecting the sheet. **I would appreciate a non-VBA answer** as I do not want to use macros on a shared file (the server is extremely slow and even normal excels take ages to save). However, if absolutely necessary, can you ninjas please tell me how I can set it up so that this problem is solved with the least possible performance hit?

P.S.: I am pretty new to VBA (practically uninitiated, I prefer R for everything). Also, the shared server is basically a network folder, so it is not likely that it will cause any issues other than being super-sloth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you protect a sheet, then only unlocked cells can be edited, that is, users can change the cell manually.

That is the core and purpose of sheet protection.

In a protected sheet you will not be able to perform a text to columns manually.

Whether or not the file lives on a server is totally unrelated to using VBA for a solution.

The real question is: What are you trying to achieve? Your question is about running Text to Columns on a protected sheet, but if you step back from that particular approach, there may be other ways to achieve what you really need to do.

Comment: I am now trying the "Allow Users to edit Ranges" option. I have to check it further. but it allows for text to column. What I want is a field where users will paste data from a delimited txt. That field will be supported by some columns of protected formulae. This hybrid data will then be fed to a Pivot (using dynamic named ranges) to provide the output. My average user is very much Excel illiterate, so the need for protecting the formulae is very important.

Comment: Consider using Power Query to get the data into Excel. The user can specify the file name in an Excel cell and Power Query can take that as a parameter and load the txt file, splice it into columns etc. Build the pivot table on that. Then the user changes the txt file name and clicks Refresh All to load data from another txt file.

Comment: Wow! Really nice. Next tym going to do that. This tym deadline was today, so I just added another sheet for text 2 columns